# DotNetNuke. how to update jquery from 1.4.4 to latest?

Tags: jquery, dotnetnuke

DotNetNuke generated link to OLD JQuery version. i need to update jquery to latest version
how?

thank you

Comment: See:  http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Login as Host (or another Super User account)
2. Goto Host-> Host Settings
3. Find jQuery Settings
4. It's generally best to check the "Use Hosted jQuery Version" box and then make sure the URL below that is pointing where you want it to.